# Flutter app waiting on white blank screen

Tags: flutter, app-store-connect

App Store says flutter IOS app waiting white blank screen and App Store reject my project. My app is running debug mode on my simulator device. Also app dont says any error in debug mode. But waiting blank screen on release mode. By the way I use getx. Please help me.

I tried again upload push notification and distribution, development certificate but id didnt worked.

Comment: Did you get any box constraints errors or warnings?

Comment: try to run in release mode and check if you face any issue or not

Comment: Try release mode with `flutter run --release`. Does it work?

Comment: Open Xcode and please check  the GoogleService-Info is there in the Runner folder. If it is not there just right click there and open Add files to "Runner" and select the GoogleService-Info.plist file. And try again

Comment: its about your developer account restriction. Check out if you have valid developer account.